# Run-time error '1004' Method 'Worksheets' of object'_Global' failed

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I believe i have an unqualified reference issue with the code below, based on what I've read. I think what I need to do is reference the workbook specifically however I've tried a number of ways of doing this, all unsuccessfully. Is anyone able to assist?

```
Dim f As FileDialog, str As String
Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
f.Show
str = f.SelectedItems(1)
    
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Set xl = New Excel.Application
xl.Visible = True
xl.Workbooks.Open (str)
                    
Dim wsT As Worksheet, wsA As Worksheet, wsE As Worksheet, wsI As   Worksheet, lr As Long, lrow As Long
            
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "TABLE"
                                   
Set wsA = Worksheets("ACTIVE")
Set wsT = Worksheets("TABLE")
```

One example, of what I've tried was

```
Set wb = xl.workbooks.open(str)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Just define the variables first.

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Set xl = New Excel.Application
xl.Visible = True

Dim xlWB as Excel.Workbook '** added this line
Set xlWB = xl.Workbooks.Open(str)
```

Rest of code looks good at first glance

Comment: Thanks. I updated the code then added xlWB.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "TABLE" but I am still getting the runtime error. Any idea why?

Comment: `xlWB.Worksheets.Add(After:=xlWB.Worksheets(1)).Name = "TABLE"`  When automating Excel from another application you need to be sure to qualify *everything* "owned" by the Excel instance.